# java.exe heavy reading of symantec virus definition

Tags: java, anti-virus, io, procmon

I've noticed that a java application (IBM Webpsphere) is running slower than it used to be and doing a lot of IO. When I opened process monitor I saw a weird behavior: it was reading Symantec virus definition file thousands of times.
Can you tell me why this happens and how to prevent it?

[image: process monitor]

Comment: Can you exclude Websphere from Reading those files?

Comment: Looks like malware to me. Java is exploited by malware.

Comment: Can't exclude. Today I saw not only java.exe reads it but Chrome also.